# CodeDeployが失敗する docker-compose コマンドがありません

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose

EC2にssh時にはdocker-composeが実行できるが，
CodeDeploy時にはdocker-composeが実行できない．

以下のコマンドで，エラーが出ている
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

スクリプトの中で以下の様に記述されていますが、環境変数 `PATH` に設定するのは **ディレクトリ** です。

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/docker-compose:$PATH"
```

`docker-compose` がコマンド名で、インストール先が `/usr/local/bin` であるなら、以下の様に修正してみてください。

**修正後:**

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: 解決しました．ありがとうございます！